# changing input checkbox checked attribute witth javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, checkbox

I'm trying to change input's values with jQuery. Values are changing properly, but the mark / unmark on the input box is not shown... I've tried if it is a problem with position or padding, but it is different problem and I'm kind of stacked.

Here is the code for changing input values:

```
    $('.AlarmsTreeView-Title input').click(function () {
        var isChecked = $(this).val();
        if (isChecked == "false") {
            $(this).attr('value', 'true').attr('checked','true');
        } else {
            $(this).attr('value', 'false').removeAttr('checked');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `.attr()` it should be

```
attr('checked','checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

Its recommended to use .prop() instead of .attr() for checked as you want to access the *property* "checked".
So instead, you can use

```
$(this).prop('checked',true);
```

and

```
$(this).prop('checked',false);
```

Check out the documentation of [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) for more clarification.

Comment: I tried both of them and still no result, but in the generated HTML the values are changing properly...

Comment: can you post the updated code or a jsFiddle link of what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    if (isChecked) {
        //do something
    } else {
        //do something
    }
```